# SONAR Caused by: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory

Tags: asp.net, nullpointerexception, sonarqube

I'm trying to get SONAR Quber to analyze an ASP.NET site built with .aspx files in .Net 2.0.  I'm getting an error of:  java.lang.NullPointerException  (more details below).

I believe that the cause has to do with the "PhysicalPath" settings in my .sln file (see below).  I've tried using both relative and full physical paths in this values.

```
Project("{E24C65DC-7377-472B-9ABA-BC803B73C61A}") = ""ECommerce", "..\ECommerce", "{9155C3E9-E34B-4C39-AE8A-ABD5B44FAB8A}"
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    TargetFramework = "2.0"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/ECommerce"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\Projects\ECommerce\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\ECommerce\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/ECommerce"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "..\..\Projects\ECommerce\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\ECommerce\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
    VWDPort = "3687"
EndProjectSection
```

EndProject

Error Message (more):

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.File.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.microsoft.ModelFactory.getWebProject(ModelFactory.java:465)
    at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.microsoft.ModelFactory.getProjects(ModelFactory.java:287)
    at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.api.microsoft.ModelFactory.getSolution(ModelFactory.java:198)
    at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.createVisualStudioSolution(VisualStudioProjectBuilder.java:185)
    at org.sonar.plugins.dotnet.core.VisualStudioProjectBuilder.build(VisualStudioProjectBuilder.java:82)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.bootstrap.ProjectBuilder.build(ProjectBuilder.java:67)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectReactorReady.start(ProjectReactorReady.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ...
```

Any help is appreciated!

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got twice the entry "Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath", and you're missing "Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath" - this is why you get this error.

Comment: I don't believe this is applicable as I'm running SONAR Qube on a Windows server, not Linux.

Comment: OK, I looked more carefully, and I found your issue so I edited my answer.